# VS Code, git bash, ng serve stopped recompiling an application. Why?

Tags: angular, git, visual-studio-code, git-bash, recompile

I am using VS Code. Inside VS Code I use a git bash. I run my Angular app using the `ng serve` from that git bash. All the time app would recompile itself if there would be changes made to the codebase.

But just now it stopped recompiling itself. Restart of the PC did not help.

Before the app stopped recompiling I was just writing code. I was not modifying any settings anywhere and I was not changing any Angular app related settings. I was literally writing some business logic in typescript in an Angular component.

I was hoping that someone had a similar issue, was able to solve it and would be generous to share a solution with me.

---

Just found out that the issue is directly related to VS Code. Because, after changing files using the Notepad++ the recompilation happens.

Comment: Yea, that is strange. Try to eliminate an application then. Try opening an HTML file in notepad and have the app running in command prompt. Change the HTML and save and see if recompile works. If it does, then keep command prompt and move over to VS Code. If this works, try integrated command prompt (not bash) and try same experiment. I think bit by bit like this you can eliminate an application in your workflow. If notepad and command prompt doesn't work, then maybe it is your PC. Maybe try a different PC to eliminate issue with PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I did not find a reason for the issue, I found a solution. Removing the `node_modules` folder and running the `npm i` afterwards solved the issue.

Comment: After some time I am facing the same issue.